# What is wrong with the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

What is wrong with the following sentence?

> "Today, we have to be complacent with pasta."

Comment: Please explain why it sounds 'off' to you. Otherwise, you could get comments along that lines that perhaps Pasta was a dog and it didn't require complacency as a training measure.

Comment: This is proof reading, so off topic.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing grammatically wrong with the sentence. (One can quibble with Pasta being a proper noun, but depending on the broader context, it might very well be one.)

The problem I see with the sentence is that complacency isn't something one 'has to be'. It's something one 'becomes' or a state one 'falls into'.

> **complacent** *adjective*
>   Showing smug or uncritical satisfaction with oneself or one's achievements.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/complacent)

If you were talking about *pasta* the food, perhaps you intended to use the term "content" instead of complacent.

> **content** *adjective*
>   1.1 Willing to accept something; satisfied.
>   ‘he had to be content with third place’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/content)